# Redirecting From An Old Permalink Structure

Tags: permalinks, redirect

We recently launched a new site that has a different permalink stucture than its prior one.

Old site URL was like this:
http://centerline.net/blog/detail/?p=3989

New like this:
http://centerline.net/cxo-content-conversations-part-1-is-your-content-lacking-eminence/

Simply setting up a 301 redirect doesn't work:
Redirect 301 http://centerline.net/blog/detail/?p=3989 http://centerline.net/cxo-content-conversations-part-1-is-your-content-lacking-eminence/

I'm assuming that something in the new installs rewrite rules is fighting with it. Is there a way to systematically redirect from the old site's URLs to the new ones?

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a tool like [Velvet Blues Update URLs](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/velvet-blues-update-urls/) to help you update all of your URLs automatically for you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I actually am having some success with this plugin doing what I need it:
Quick Page/Post Redirect Plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/